# lowdb updates only one infos in JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lowdb

I make a lowdb request to update a JSON file, but only the date is updated. When I make a console.log of the information to update, this is what I want to update:

```
res.on("end", function () {
            let body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            let final = JSON.parse(body);
            if (final.error !== undefined) {
                console.log("Initial authentication:", final.error_description, "Please refresh the authentication grant");
                extAuthCallback(84);
            } else {
                tokens.set('access_token', final.access_token)
                    .set('expires_in', final.expires_in)
                    .set('refresh_token', final.refresh_token)
                    .set('refresh_date', moment())
                    .write()
                console.log(final, tokens.value())
                extAuthCallback(1);
            }
        });
```

console.log of my final variable:

```
{
  access_token: 'oa_prod_iq00cRPk5Jhh4VffSHlDj7DEDsSIlpCRRczI3l3ASC0',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  expires_in: 2399,
  refresh_token: 'oa_prod_nIjBZs74xGvJXi1B-wdMyITfxGyklpCRRczI3l3ASC0'
}
```

console.log of my JSON file after the request:

```
{
  access_token: 'oa_prod_pB9Q0FFM9Tk4c5n3HMRBFKAVz6naiJ-jmb3QCeBrT00',
  expires_in: 2399,
  refresh_token: 'oa_prod_nX3EDs530SM8eHv_fM5BN7-5RLBwkrKoUi6uExBbTY4',
  refresh_date: '2020-11-28T23:31:13.855Z',
  primary_autorization_date: '2020-11-29T00:40:58.421Z'
}
```

My JSON file after the modifications:

```
{
  "access_token": "oa_prod_pB9Q0FFM9Tk4c5n3HMRBFKAVz6naiJ-jmb3QCeBrT00",
  "expires_in": 2399,
  "refresh_token": "oa_prod_nX3EDs530SM8eHv_fM5BN7-5RLBwkrKoUi6uExBbTY4",
  "refresh_date": "2020-11-28T23:31:13.855Z",
  "primary_autorization_date": "2020-11-29T00:40:58.421Z"
}
```

So it only has the `primary_autorization_date` field changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is:

I call my function that contains the HTTP request in another file like this:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    const access_token = req.query.code;
    if (access_token) {
        let authentication = await asyncExtAuth(access_token);
        if (authentication == 84)
            return res.send({error: "Please give a valid access_token"});
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/success_page/index.html'));
        db.set('access_token', access_token).write()
        tokens.set('primary_autorization_date', moment()).write()
        console.log("Access Token successfully refreshed")
    }
    else
        res.send({error: "Please specify an access token"})
})
```

In which I modify a second time my file with the line `tokens.set('primary_autorization_date', moment()).write()`. By doing this, lowdb doesn't take into account the modification made just before and re-modifies my file with the information it contained before. The solution is to add the line `tokens.read()` just before modifying the file to update the cache:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    const access_token = req.query.code;
    if (access_token) {
        let authentication = await asyncExtAuth(access_token);
        if (authentication == 84)
            return res.send({error: "Please give a valid access_token"});
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/success_page/index.html'));
        db.set('access_token', access_token).write()
        tokens.read()
        tokens.set('primary_autorization_date', moment()).write()
        console.log("Access Token successfully refreshed")
    }
    else
        res.send({error: "Please specify an access token"})
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `set` instead of `update`.

```
tokens.set('access_token', final.access_token)
    .set('expires_in', final.expires_in)
    .set('refresh_token', final.refresh_token)
    .set('refresh_date', moment())
    .write()
```

The update method is accepted a function like this.

```
db.update('test1', (n) => 5555)
  .update('test2', (n) => n + 1)
  .write()
```

If you use `set`, you just need to assign the value to it.

```
db.set('test1', 5555).set('test2', 3333).write()
```

And when you use `moment`, there are two ways to you could use.

```
// Way 1 with moment()
db.set('date', moment()).write()

// Way 2 with moment
db.update('date', moment).write()
```

Comment: So yes at the beginning I was using `.set` but it didn't change anything in my JSON file. When I made a console.log of `tokens.value()` I realized that it was modified but the modification doesn't appear in my JSON file...

Comment: Where do you write this filed `primary_autorization_date`? I don't see any code to `set` or `update` this field.

Comment: I've found the solution, I redact this within 1 hour. Thank's for your help!